# How can I anchor a Reality Composer (RealityKit) scene to a detected image

Tags: image, anchor, scene, realitykit, reality-composer

Anchor RealityKit Scene to Image Target

I have tried using the limited documentation to write the code but I haven't succeeded. I can only get a scene to anchor to a horizontal plane.

Can anyone suggest some simple code that would link a scene made in reality composer to an image target?

How would I= change/add to this code below?

```
let arConfiguration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
arConfiguration.planeDetection = .horizontal
arView.session.run(arConfiguration)

guard let anchor = try? Spinner.loadScene() else { return }
arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup an image anchor directly in RC? It's quite straight forward, I can explain if it helps.

I have found that the model drifts slightly when using an image anchor, I hope this gets fixed soon.